# Socket Session getting closed after single message

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket

Debugging is being using Simple Web Socket Client.

So, my socket gets active on port X,

I successfully get the "Hello new client" message on Client.

When i send the first request/data to the server, server receives it and prints on console.

Post this, as soon as I send another request, session closed event is being triggered.

I checked Session's TimeOut: 60secs and KeepAliveTime: 600secs, which seem fine.

below is the code for SocketServer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start the server!");

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();


        var bootstrap = BootstrapFactory.CreateBootstrap();


        if (!bootstrap.Initialize())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to initialize!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        var result = bootstrap.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Start result: {0}!", result);

        if (result == StartResult.Failed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to start!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        foreach (WebSocketServer appS in bootstrap.AppServers)
        {
            appS.NewDataReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, byte[]>(appServer_NewDataReceived);
            appS.NewSessionConnected += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession>(appServer_NewSessionConnected);
            appS.SessionClosed += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, CloseReason>(appServer_SessionClosed);
            appS.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(appServer_NewMessageReceived);     
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press key 'q' to stop it!");

        Char input;
        while ((input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 'q')
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            continue;
        }


        Console.WriteLine();

        //Stop the appServer
        bootstrap.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The server was stopped!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void appServer_NewDataReceived(WebSocketSession session, byte[] message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client said: " + message);
        //Send the received message back
        session.Send("Server responded back: " + message);
    }

    private static void appServer_NewSessionConnected(WebSocketSession session)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("New session connected! Sessions counter: " );
        session.Send("Hello new client!");
    }

    private static void appServer_SessionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseReason value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected! Sessions counter: ");
    }

    private static void appServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client said: " + message);
        //Send the received message back
        session.Send("Server responded back: " + message);
    }
```

Error on close is "Protocol Error"